# Compare 2 nsmutablearray and get different object to third array in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I want to compare 2 `NSMutableArray` and  get different object into third `Array`. How can i do that ?

Array1 can loop object .

```
Array1 = "a", "b","c","d","a","b","c";
Array2 = "a", "b", "c";
```

And then result

```
Array3 = "d";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should array3 just be `[ "d" ]`, or should it be `[ "b", "d" ]`, your question isn't clear about what 'diff object' means?

Comment: Are the objects strings? Also, are you looking for equality (the value is the same) or identity (which objects in array1 occupy the same memory as the objects in array2)?

Comment: @Maarten: Yes, it is a object

Answer (score 21):

Use sets for set operations:

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:array1];
NSMutableSet *set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];
[set2 minusSet:set1];
```

Comment: @NGOT, are you using really string literals as in the question, or some objects of a custom class?

Comment: @NGOT: You have to swap `array1` and `array2` because in this answer, `array2` is the "larger" array.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, sorry for expecting people to know highschool maths. I apologize. `</sarcasm>` - and thanks for explaining that to OP.

Comment: Array1 is array response from server, and array2 is array copy from Array1. I want after server reponse data to array1, I compare array1 and array2, if in Array2 dont have object which from Array1, reloadTable.

Comment: @H2CO3 This is the best and the most helpful answer I've ever seen! So lovely! Thanks. (:

Comment: It works fine, but result on set is changing index of values and that is creating a problem for me. Is there any substitute that won't change index of stored data and just to remove set1's data from set2?

Answer (score 7):

You Can try this too.

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"1", nil];
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"2",@"1", nil];    

NSMutableArray *largeArray;
NSMutableArray *shortArray;
if([array1 count] > [array2 count]){
    largeArray = array1;
    shortArray = array2; 
} else {
    largeArray = array2;
    shortArray = array1; 
}
[largeArray removeObjectsInArray:shortArray];

for (NSString *va in largeArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@",va);
}
```

Comment: HOw can determine that which one is large and which one is short ?

Comment: @RanjuPatel like you have array in which you want to check the duplicates (the duplicates are also in the array).

Answer (score 5):

```
NSMutableArray *gotDiffArry= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 0 ; i < FirstArray.count; i++) {
    if(i < seconArray.count){
        if(![seconArray[i] isEqual:firstArray[i]]){
             [gotDiffArry addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
         }
    } else {
        [gotDiffArry addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < firstArray.count ; i ++)
{

 NSString *search = [firstArray objectAtIndex:i];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF CONTAINS %@", search];
 NSMutableArray *temAraay = [secondArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
 if(temArray.count >=0 )
 {
   NSLog("%@", [temArray objectAtIndex:0]); 
 }
}
```

Comment: what type of differentIndex?

Comment: This is too iterative and time consuming if arrays are large. Not an efficient way.

Comment: Thanks but i only want to get diff object not all object.

Comment: @NGOT- then use only else part of Array ...:)

Answer (score 4):

I have used the following and got the desired results:

```
for(int i =0; i<[arraytwo count]; i++)
{
    if (![arrayone containsObject:[arraytwo objectAtIndex:i]])
        [arraythree addObject: [arraytwo obectAtIndex:i]];
}    
NSLog(@"%@",arraythree);
```

Comment: Probably more efficient than the set approach (for smaller arrays, at least).

Comment: I am using it for bigger arrays too. It may take some time for bigger array, but i am doing it in background so works fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that I haven't gone through a "big O" estimation for the various schemes.  Probably the set approach is a hair more efficient for large sets, but you likely have to be in the thousands of elements for it to be significant.